# Gradle + Kotlin why don't we assign variables directly

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

In the `build.gradle.kts` there is the following code:

```
buildscript {
extra.apply {
    set("kotestVersion", "4.6.1")
    set("jdbi3Version", "3.21.0")
    set("resilience4jVersion", "1.7.1")
}
}
val kotestVersion: String by extra
val jdbi3Version: String by extra
val resilience4jVersion: String? by extra
```

Why do we need to assign values in such an indirect way? Is there a reason we do not assign a value to a variable directly, such as

```
val kotestVersion: String = "4.6.1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean why do you need to use the `set` method, that’s because these are [Gradle Lazy Properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/lazy_configuration.html#lazy_properties), and not primitive types like string or int. The Groovy syntax makes it possible for direct assignments, but Kotlin doesn’t. There’s an open ticket about it: https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/9268

Comment: makes sense, thx